# Chrome Dev Tools Snippets - AUTOSAVE

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to enable `autosave` on snippets in `chrome dev tools`?

It is infuriating when i accidentaly close a tab that `dev tools` was attached to where i had my snippets open and when i open `dev tools` again i've lost alot of work!

Are there any flags i can set to enable autosave or somehow get it to save when i run the snippet?

Just to be clear i am talking about the snippets under `Sources/Snippets`.
I know i can "just" use the shortcut `ctrl-s` to save however that is simply not good enough, i would atleast expect a recovery like all modern editors deliver.

Incase this cannot be achieved please point me the in direction where i can submit a feature request to the Chrome Dev Team

Comment: File a new issue on https://crbug.com and explicitly state that this is a feature request. Then post a link here so we can star the issue.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=755075

Answer (score 0):

Select <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Developer Tools</kbd>. The Developer Tools window opens as a docked panel at the side or bottom of Google Chrome. Click the <kbd>Network</kbd> tab. Select <kbd>Preserve log</kbd>.

Also, go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> in devtools, which is a little screw on the top-right corner, find the *Console* section under <kbd>Preferences</kbd>, and click on <kbd>Preserve log upon navigation</kbd>.

This has worked for me.